# Get an element from another page

Tags: javascript, html

How to get an element (opening and closing times) from this site https://www.costco.com/warehouse-locations/brooklyn-NY-318.html using javascript and display it on another page?

```js
element = document.getElementsByClassName('core')[0].firstElementChild.childNodes[0].data
```

Thanks

Comment: Are you pertaining to Javascript run on a browser or elsewhere like with NodeJS?

Comment: On a browser,  in google site embed HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, if you plan to do this with purely browser-based Javascript, [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS) will likely stop you from requesting the page and pulling the data there. You can try looking for an API that Costo  provides, or some other online tool that can get you that information that supports cross-origin requests.

The other solution is to create your own server script. Having a back-end like NodeJS pull the page with packages like [`axios`](http://npmjs.com/package/axios) and passing the resulting string over to [`jsdom`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/jsdom). This way, you can run the same `element` script you wrote to get the data you were looking for. I can elaborate but I'm just not sure if Google Sites has this capability.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation